# Clicking on img class to upload file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to be able to just show my img class on my view .But also use that img to be able to click on it to pop up the file selector.

How am I able to do so I not sure. I thought might be able to do it with java-script but unsure how. Do not want "No File Selected To Show.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label  for="input-image" class="col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-sm-2 col-xs-12"><?php echo $entry_image; ?></label>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
<img class="thumbnail"  src="<?php echo $image; ?>" style="width:100px; height:100px;"/>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you looked for your problem, over google??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="file" style="position:absolute;opacity:0" id="file"><img onclick="$('#file').click();">
```

with jQuery
or without it:

```
<input type="file" style="position:absolute;opacity:0" id="file"><img onclick="document.getElementById('file').click();">
```

Comment: I tested opacity:0 on IE 11 just a second ago, and it works fine.

Comment: I strongly recommend you to drop supporting IE8. It's dangerous and you're wasting time. I suggest you to make two portions of the code: One with img click event and input hidden, and other for IE8 with standard input.

Answer (score 0):

File selector is raw behavior of browser,you can only emulate the "Raw File Input" by image background and hide the raw input button by setting "opacity" style.

Refer: the profile setting page in twitter, use chrome debugger to look into elements and styles.
https://twitter.com/settings/profile

Answer (score -2):

this is a sample code taken from the folllowing [Source](http://geniuscarrier.com/how-to-style-a-html-file-upload-button-in-pure-css/)

css:

```
<style>
.element{
background-color:red;
width:200px;
}
.fileUpload {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px;
    width:200px;
}
.fileUpload input.upload {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}

</style>
```

html:

```
<input id="uploadFile" placeholder="Choose File" disabled="disabled" />
<div class="fileUpload">
    <div class="element">Upload</div>
    <input id="uploadBtn" type="file" class="upload" />
</div>
```

js:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("uploadBtn").onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById("uploadFile").value = this.value;
};
</script>
```